# How i can make a line break in Discord embed in Python?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Im trying to make a space between each embed field, I tried to use `\u200B` and `\n` but it does not work to me. ( Using Python to create discord bot)

```
async def cmd_help(self, ctxt):
    embed=discord.Embed(
        color=ctxt.author.color,
        description=f'All Command**{self.client.user.mention}**'
    )
    embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name='Server Command', value='`p!ping`>>Check the ping from server to bot.\n`p!list`>>Check the number of users in the server.',  inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Users Command', value='`!kick`>>Kick the user from server.',  inline=False)
    await ctxt.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Doesn't ``inline = False`` do that already?
or do you want extra space?

Comment: i want an extra space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to add extra space between 2 fields then that's a good workaround:

```
embed.add_field(name='Server Command', value='`p!ping`>>Check the ping from server to bot.\n`p!list`>>Check the number of users in the server.',  inline=False)
embed.add_field(name = chr(173), value = chr(173))
embed.add_field(name='Users Command', value='`!kick`>>Kick the user from server.',  inline=False)
```

What I did is that I added another field between both of them and I set its name and value to an **empty character**.

Comment: No problem happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your text within triple quotes(`''' text '''`) and then use it for the embed.

so your code should look something like this:

```
value = '''p!ping`>>Check the ping from server to bot.

   `p!list`>>Check the number of users in the server.'''


embed.add_field(name='Server Command', value=value,  inline=False)
```

A benefit of this way is that you can also add blank lines in between so that the text looks more aesthetic